# How to make TeX stop on error?

Tags: errors, texlive

How can I tell `*tex` commands from TeX Live 2013 that they should stop and exit when they detect an error instead of opening a command prompt?

Comment: Hi! Please, what operating system are you running?

Comment: I'm on Windows and Linux. My goal is to start TeX from a script and there, the interactive "fix error" mode really gets in my way.

Comment: Pass the option `-halt-on-error` to pdflatex.

Comment: @AaronDigulla Ok, then please tell me where did you installed tetex from, since that distro has been quite dead for years.

Comment: @tohecz: I got it from the TeX Live 2013 CD.

Comment: Ah ok, then it's TeXLive :) The name TeTeX is quite abandoned, so it's usage quite confused me. Sorry for that.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I'll try that. Why is that a comment and not an answer?

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks, I couldn't find that one. This question on SO contains more options for other versions of TeX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738755/dont-make-me-manually-abort-a-latex-compile-when-theres-an-error